# How to use a list of strings as listbox's datasource

Tags: c#, list, listbox, datasource

Here is the code I made, it usually works, but sometimes fails (1 out of 4 times more or less):

```
...
List<string> _items = new List<string>(); 
...
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Globals.conString))
{
    string codbultocomp = null;
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT codbultocomp FROM envios WHERE codigodestino=@codigodestino AND estado=@pendiente", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigodestino", codigoDestino);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pendiente", "pendiente");

        SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            codbultocomp = reader["codbultocomp"].ToString();
            _items.Add(codbultocomp);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = _items;
}
```

When it fails the application freezes, and if I pause the debug it is stopped in the last brace. I tried to show an error using a try/catch block but it didn't show anything and stopped in the same place. I also tried to watch the listbox datasource shows this error in the "watch" list:

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this being run on a background thread?

Comment: It's a windows CE application. The application starts with a menu with different options, this code is from one of the options. When an option is selected in the menu, a new form representing that option appears, and the menu form stays behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it after your `using`, all IDisposable objects will be disposed after `using`.

```
...
List<string> _items = new List<string>(); 
...
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Globals.conString))
{
     ...
} 

listBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

Comment: I changed it but the problem persists.

Comment: @rfc1484, I suggest use Entity Framework currently I can't test your application but may be reader.Close() is wrong here, but see the sample Entity Frame work usage from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx, to prevent from such situations, your problem is simple linq with EF.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this:

For a clear code create a method like:

```
public List<string> getItems(string codigodestino, string pendiente)
{
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Globals.conString);
    string Qyery = "SELECT codbultocomp FROM envios WHERE codigodestino='" + codigodestino + "' AND estado='" + pendiente +"'";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Qyery, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            _items.Add((string)reader["codbultocomp"]);
        }
        con.Close();
        return _items;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

and then just use:

```
listBox1.DataSource = getItems(codigoDestino, "pendiente");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just close the con object. No need to close the reader as well. The using of con object takes care. Rest using isnt required.

Comment: I think it is not the problem see MSDN sample(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx#Y600)

Comment: Anyway I tried it again with that correction and the application still freezes from time to time in the same spot.

Comment: @rfc1484, I didnt propose an asnwer, instead asked you to simplify your code for better understanding and simplicity.